# Can the world line of a particle be successively differentiated to any order to always give a four-vector?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, vectors

Starting with the world line of a particle given by $x^{\mu}$, this can be successively differentiated with the particle's proper time $\tau$ to give the four-velocity from the four-position, four-acceleration from the four-velocity. I'd expect to be able to do this to any order creating another four-vector, but I'm not sure if I'm missing some mathematical subtlety which doesn't guarantee this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In special relativity in the usual coordinate system, the answer is yes, any number of derivatives with respect to proper time gives you a four-vector with respect to Lorentz transformations.

But in general, the answer is no. If $x^\mu(\tau)$ are the coordinates of the worldline as a function of its proper time (assuming a timelike worldline), then 
$$
 \frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}
\tag{1}
$$
is always a four-vector, but
$$
 \frac{d^2 x^\mu}{d\tau^2}
\tag{2}
$$
is not always a four-vector (or any other tensor). In flat spacetime with metric 
$$
d\tau^2=\eta_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu\,dx^\nu
\tag{3}
$$
with coordinate-independent coefficients $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, it is a four-vector with respect to coordinate transformations that preserve the form (3). But in general it is not a four-vector. In general, to get a four-vector corresponding to the worldline's "acceleration," the quantity (3) should be replaced by
$$
 \frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}\nabla_\nu\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}
\tag{4}
$$
where $\nabla$ is the covariant derivative. Explicitly,
\begin{align}
 \frac{dx^\alpha}{d\tau}\nabla_\alpha\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}
&=
\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\tau}\left(
 \partial_\alpha\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}
 +\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}
 \frac{dx^\beta}{d\tau}
\right)
\\
&=
 \frac{d^2 x^\mu}{d\tau^2}
 +\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}
 \frac{dx^\alpha}{d\tau}
 \frac{dx^\beta}{d\tau}
\tag{5}
\end{align}
where the coefficients $\Gamma$ are the Christoffel symbols. The quantity (4) or (5) is a four-vector in any spacetime and in any coordinate system. When the metric has the form (3) with coordinate-independent $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ (which implies both flat spacetime and a special coordinate system), then $\Gamma=0$ and (4) reduces to (2).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you differentiate a four-vector with respect to a scalar, you get another four-vector.

Comment: This is assuming that the four-trajectory of the particle is actually differentiable to whatever order you want in the first place, which may not be guaranteed.